# Converting raw byte data to audio

Tags: java, android

In my application, I want to change the raw byte data to the audio. So, at first I receive the data and add it to a byte array list and than I want to change the whole array list to the audio. As the data is raw through audio jack, I would appreciate if you let me know which audio format is suitable (wav,3gp and so on)? Also, I have a problem with saving this data in a file. This is my code. in line of fileOuputStream.write( audiod.toArray()), it give an error and asked me to change the type of audiod to byte.

```
private static ArrayList<Byte> audiod = new ArrayList<Byte>();
audioFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myaudio.wav";

if (dg == 1) {
    //audiod.append(data[i]);
    for (int i = 0; data != null && i < data.length; i++) {
        audiod.add(data[i]);
    }
    if (stt.equalsIgnoreCase(("r"))) {
        dg = 0;
        recordButton.setEnabled(true);
        File file = new File(audioFilePath);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(audioFilePath);
            fileOuputStream.write( audiod.toArray());
            fileOuputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`audiod.toArray()` will give you a `Byte[]`, however you need a `byte[]`. In Java there are so called wrapper classes for the primitive data types. A `Byte` is an object that holds `byte` values.

Why do you use a list of `Byte` at all? It needs a lot more memory than a simple `byte[]` you seem to have anyhow (`data`).

The data format (wav,3gp and so on) depends on how you got your data.

Comment: As you can see, I want to add data to Audiod and I am not sure what will be the size of Audiod. If I define Audiod as byte, is there any way that I can add data[i] (which is a byte) to that?...

Comment: I'd write the data directly to a file, or if you really have to keep it in memory a `ByteArrayOutputStream` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) could be used. It grows the underlying byte array as necessary.